# How to get url object from response object of Rest Client

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to solve a problem   mentioned below

Query this web service 100 times:

```
http://www.randomwebsite.com/cgi-bin/random.pl
```

The response contains a short HTML document with one link inside. Query this link and store link URL, as well as the returned HTTP response codes in a suitable data structure.
The application should output a list of all link URLs ordered by the first character of the domain name (ignore http:// and www prefixes) and also print the related HTTP Code, if it’s not 200.

I am trying to use jersey client

```
Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource2 = client.resource("http://www.randomwebsite.com/cgi-bin/random.pl");

            ClientResponse response2 = webResource2.accept("text/html").get(ClientResponse.class);

            System.out.println(response2);

            if (response2.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response2.getStatus());
            }

            String output2 = response2.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("\n============getFtoCResponse============");
            System.out.println(output2);


GET http://www.westciv.com/ returned a response status of 200 OK
```

Now the problem is to store the URI i am not able to get the uri.How to get URI from the response object.I am able to see the random url  in response2  when its printed.But not able to get as a object to see the URL.I cannot get from client because the randomwebsite redirects to  random site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response sent is a redirect, with status 302. Your client allows [not following redirects automatically](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html#setFollowRedirects%28java.lang.Boolean%29):

```
client.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

You should get the URL from the `Location` response header.

Comment: Thats cool works for me thank you.One doubt though if the request to redirected url fails will I get 302 or 40x/50x? How to handle error case?

Comment: You won't have any request to the redirected URL if you disable redirect followup. The status you get when sending a request depends on the server. If the resource doesn't exist, you'll get a 404. If the server has an internal error, you'll get a 500, etc.

Comment: ok then I  get this redirected url and  call it again to get the status so 2 rest calls I have to make?

Comment: Yes,or course: a first request to www.randomwebsite.com, and a second one to whatever URL randomwebsite returns.

Comment: I am trying to do a get  the random url usign curl .. curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://www.randomwebsite.com/cgi-bin/random.pl
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Server: nginx
    Date: Mon, 25 May 2015 12:05:33 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    Location: http://www.copvcia.com/
    ngpass_ngall: 1
    Content-Length: 207
    Age: 0
    Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>302 Found</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Found</h1>
    <p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.copvcia.com/">here</a>.</p>
    </body></html>

Comment: It's in the Location header of the response. Read the javadoc: https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientResponse.html#getHeaders%28%29

Comment: in curl i get diffrent response.I get a simple html document with redirect url embedded but in jersey client i get actual html page itself!

Comment: Have you called setFollowRedirects(false), as my answer tells you to do? If you don't, the client automatically follows the redirect and thus automatically does the second request. You said it worked for you in your first comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78686/discussion-between-javascriptlearner-and-jb-nizet).